# How to split a string with <br> in xml using xslt-1.0

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

This is part of the HTML I would like to transform using XSLT

```
<tr>
<td>ELE1600A  </td>
<td>CIRCUITS ELECTRIQUES                         <br>Chahe Nerguizian                                  </td>
<td><center>01&nbsp;</center></td>
<td><center>01&nbsp;</center></td>
<td><center>03</center></td>
</tr>
```

I would like to split the following

```
<td>CIRCUITS ELECTRIQUES                         <br>Chahe Nerguizian                                  </td>
```

into :

1. CIRCUITS ELECTRIQUES
2. Chahe Nerguizian

I've tried using

```
<xsl:valuf-of select="substring-before(td[2],'&#xA;')"/>
<xsl:valuf-of select="substring-after(td[2],'&#xA;')"/>
```

but it does not return anything to me in both php's and eclipse's XSLT Processor.
Any tough on how could I achieve this ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your input markup is not XHTML, therefore not XML, therefore not well formed (see unclosed `br`). This kind of input will never work with any kind of XSLT processor. Also the question is a bit unclear. You ask for a wanted HTML numeric list, but from the shown XSLT fragment you are just concatenating values.

Comment: Your XML isn't well formed. 1. `br` has no closing tag 2. XML hasn't predefined entity `&nbsp;`

Comment: He said it's HTML, not XML. `<br>` and `&nbsp;` are quite legal in HTML. However, that does make XSLT impossible.

Comment: In fact, I didn't really wanted to have a list, juste have them in separated elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you have not got XHTML here, and therefore not XML, and so XSLT cannot be used on it. However.... **IF** it was amended to be XML, you could do something with it.

Imagine this was the starting document, which is well-formed:

```
<tr>
    <td>ELE1600A </td>
    <td>CIRCUITS ELECTRIQUES<br />Chahe Nerguizian 
    </td>
    <td>
        <center>01 </center>
    </td>
    <td>
        <center>01 </center>
    </td>
    <td>
        <center>03</center>
    </td>
</tr>
```

You can then make use of the identity transform, with extra matching templates to handle matching the **td** element which has **br** elements as children.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

   <xsl:output method="html" />

   <xsl:template match="td[br]">
      <xsl:copy>
         <ol>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
         </ol>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="td[br]/node()">
      <li>
         <xsl:call-template name="IdentityTransform" />
      </li>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="td[br]/br">
      <!-- Ignore tag -->
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:call-template name="IdentityTransform" />
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template name="IdentityTransform">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When this is applied to the input XML, the following is generated:

```
<tr>
    <td>ELE1600A </td>
    <td>
        <ol>
            <li>CIRCUITS ELECTRIQUES </li>
            <li>Chahe Nerguizian </li>
        </ol>
    </td>
    <td>
        <center>01 </center>
    </td>
    <td>
        <center>01 </center>
    </td>
    <td>
        <center>03</center>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Thank you, your answer helped me a lot even if my question was not really clear, works perfectly with the td[br]/node().

Comment: In face, this is what i've used :
<nom>
<xsl:value-of select="td[2]/node()"/>
</nom>
<prof>
<xsl:value-of select="td[2]/node()[last()]"/>
</prof>

to get

<nom>CIRCUITS ELECTRIQUES </nom>
<prof>Chahe Nerguizian</prof>